# xng breadcrumb routes undefined in child module

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, xng-breadcrumb

I'm using xng-breadcrumb library from this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xng-breadcrumb

Everything is normal when using breadcrumb in children component, but when in lazy load children module, the breadcrumb is not working and it shows

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'routes')

this is my child module to be lazy loaded in **app.routing.module.ts**

**qna.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        QnaComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        QnaRoutingModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        QnaService
    ],
})
export class QnaModule {
}
```

and this is my routing module

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            {
                path: '',
                data: {
                    breadcrumb: {
                        label: 'my home',
                        info: 'home',
                        routeInterceptor: (routeLink) => {
                            return routeLink;
                        },
                    },
                },   
                component: AppMainComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'pages/qna',
                        loadChildren: () => import('../app/controllers/qna/qna.module').then(x => 
                         x.QnaModule),
                        data: {breadcrumb: 'QnA', roles: ["Admin"]},
                        // canActivate: [AuthGuard]
                    },
                ]

  ], {
            // scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
            // anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
            // useHash: true,
            relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'
        })
    ],
```

should i use another library or is there a way to fix xng-breadcrumb work in lazy loading children module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After upgrading to xng breadcrumb version 8.02 it works for angular 14